# Simple DoS protection with mod_security?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, mod-security

I have mod **security2** in **ubuntu 14.04 LTS server**.
I saw the below tutorial:
http://blog.cherouvim.com/simple-dos-protection-with-mod_security/

The above sadly do not work on me apache error :

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                            [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 226 of /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf:
ModSecurity: No action id present within the rule
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

The Apache error log may have more information.

Can you recommend something similar?

Answer (score 3):

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/modsecurity-apache

Ubuntu has ModSecurity 2.7+ which requires [1]

- Added Rules must have ID action and must be numeric.

So best would be to add ID's to those rules and that will do the trick.
For instance rule

```
SecRule ip:block "@eq 1" "phase:1,deny,log,logdata:'req/sec: %{ip.requests}, blocks: %{ip.blocks}',status:403"
```

should be

```
SecRule ip:block "@eq 1" "id:12345,phase:1,deny,log,logdata:'req/sec: %{ip.requests}, blocks: %{ip.blocks}',status:403"
```

Or some other ID which is not already used by some other rule.

[1] https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/blob/master/CHANGES